# php build error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lltdl

Tags: php, make

I am not a build guru and could use a pointer.  I'm trying to make php5 on linux.  I have successfully run config.  I run make and get the following error:

```
/bin/sh libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=link gcc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -Iinclude -Imain -I/home/jspeirs/webdev/stack/php-5.3.10 -Iext/date/lib -Iext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include -Iext/mbstring/oniguruma -Iext/mbstring/libmbfl -Iext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/mysql -Iext/sqlite3/libsqlite -ITSRM -IZend    -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden   -o ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath modules -L/usr/lib6464 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.lo ext/mcrypt/mcrypt_filter.lo -lmcrypt -lltdl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lltdl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Make: [ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.la] Error 1
```

I know that /usr/bin/ld exists but I have no clue what -lltdl is. I have looked at the ld help docs with no insight.  I have tried searching for more help with no results.  If someone could help get me on track I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
yum install libtool-ltdl-devel
```

And then re-run your build.

Answer (score 1):

check value of environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
in your case it should be `/usr/bin`

just run

```
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin
```